# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I am trying to create a new table in a database which has a name of checkout and a check number which ive put in {0}. But when I run the program it comes up with the error shown in the title for the "Productlist varchar(50)"

```
SQLiteCommand tableCreateCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
tableCreateCommand.CommandText = string.Format("create table Checkout{0} (ID int, Productlist varchar{0}, Date varchar {0}, Time varchar (50), Total double)");
tableCreateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Are you replacing the `{0}` with other text before running the command?  If so, can you show us the replacement?  Otherwise, what is the purpose of the `{0}`'s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified any values for the placeholders in String.Format.

```
string.Format("create table Checkout{0} (ID int, Productlist varchar{0}, 
Date varchar {0}, Time varchar (50), Total double)",  <you need to specify  
the list of values for place holders here...>)
```

It should be something like this. Note the values specified from second parameter onwards. You can use a constant or some variable in place of constants shown here. The value specified after the comma will replace the placeholders in the index order. `{0}` will use value **123456**, `{1}` would use **50**, `{2}` would use **65** and `{3}` would use **75**.

```
string.Format("create table Checkout{0} (ID int, Productlist varchar({1}), 
Date varchar({2}), Time varchar ({3}), Total double)", 123456, 50, 65, 75)
```

If you need to use the same placeholder for varchar as specified for checkout, it should be like this. I am not sure if this is your intention. Here all place holders {0} will use the same value 100.

```
string.Format("create table Checkout{0} (ID int, Productlist varchar({0}), 
Date varchar({0}), Time varchar (50), Total double)", 100)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `string.Format` including `{0}` in various places, indicating that you want a placeholder to be replaced... but you're not providing the placeholder value.

You want something like:

```
tableCreateCommand.CommandText = string.Format("...", checkNumber);
```

However, I suspect you *actually* want multiple parameters (`{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}` etc) rather than just one. What SQL are you *expecting* from the result of `string.Format`?

Comment: The reason I have Checkout{0} is there is more than one checkout which can send transactions to the server so the {0} represents the checkout number

Comment: @TweedyMK: But you're *also* using `{0}` in two other places. What values were you expecting there to be? And how did you expect `string.Format` to get the checkout number?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed a string to string.Format that it needs to place into your {0} place-holder. Are you missing a variable?

```
...string.Format("your long format string {0}", someMissingStringVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this sample you've called `String.Format` with a string containing place holders `{0}` but provided no arguments.  You need to either remove the place holders or provide an argument to fill in the `{0}` slot

If you want to literally put `{0}` into the string then don't use `String.Format` or properly escape them via `{{0}}`.